# Is there latexmk functionality for LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, latexmk

I am a big fan of `latexmk` and lately I have been looking a bit towards LuaTeX. However I am yet to find a way to get the functionality of latexmk (mainly recompilation on changes and automatic rerun an appropriate number of times to resolve cross references and such) for LuaTex. Is there something similar and if not how do you LuaTeX people survive without it? :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use `Lua(La)TeX` with `latexmk` by setting the `-pdflatex` parameter:

> `-pdflatex=<program>` - set program used for pdflatex.
>                        (replace '`<program>`' by the program name)

So `latexmk` should call `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` if you invoke it like this:

```
latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf <texfile>
```

or with newer versions of `latexmk` there is direct `Lua(La)TeX`/`XeLaTeX` support:

> -lualatex
>     Use lualatex.  That is, use lualatex to process the source file(s) to pdf (in place of pdflatex).
>     This option is exactly equivalent to specifying the following sequence of options:
>   -pdflatex="lualatex %O %S" -pdf -dvi- -ps-

Comment: How can one pass `--shell-escape`?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of adding the `-lualatex` flag to each application of `latexmk`, you could 
place the following

```
$pdflatex = 'lualatex -file-line-error %O %S';
$pdf_mode = 1;
```

in an '.latexmkrc' file. This file should reside in your home folder, if you use
`lualatex` in all your jobs, or in the folder(s) where your `lualatex` jobs are.

More generally, you will find a host of examples and boilerlate code for `.latexmkrc` in the [respective CTAN repository](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles)

Answer (score 12):

Since version `4.51` of latexmk, you can use the following `.latexmkrc`:

```
$pdf_mode = 4;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
```

Comment: For the second line `$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;`, I think both default to false/0 anyway.

Comment: For more info [latexmk man page](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/support/latexmk/latexmk.txt): "$pdf_mode [0] ... If equal to 4, generate a pdf version of the document using lualatex".

Answer (score 5):

The following syntax is valid, as of `latexmk` 4.80. To have `latexmk` use LuaLaTeX to build a PDF file (the usual choice), just do

```
latexmk -pdflua foo.tex
```

Alternatively you could use the seemingly equivalent `-lualatex` option instead of `-pdflua`. To add the `-shell-escape` option, since this was asked about in a comment, just do

```
latexmk -pdflua -shell-escape foo.tex
```

This is directly from the documentation one obtains from `texdoc latexmk`, namely the `latexmk` manual. One can get a shorter help summary from `latexmk -h` or `latexmk --help`. There is also some additional documentation in the `latexmk` source file, which is a Perl script, specifically about how `latexmk` detects build dependencies.

Additional comment. The current manual says the following

> -lualatex

> Use lualatex. That is, use lualatex to process the source file(s) to pdf. The generation of dvi and postscript files is turned off. This option is equivalent to using the following set of options

> -pdflua -dvi- -ps-

This appears to be incorrect or out of date. Perhaps it was correct once. But just using `-pdflua` does not generate any DVI or PostScript files. It would be surprising if it did. So I presume the `-lualatex` and the `-pdflua` options are the same. At any rate, I cannot see any differences between them.

Comment: Technically, if everything is as it appears, `-lualatex` does do the same thing as `-pdflua -dvi- -ps-` (and both these options are equivalent to `-pdflua`). It is inaccurate to say the manual is "incorrect"; maybe it would be more accurate to say the manual is "misleading" because it adds the extra `-dvi- -ps-` when there is no need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I currently run MacTeX under macOS Ventura, and I use `lualatex` as my default engine for everything nowadays. This is my current `.latexmkrc` file, which I keep in my home directory.

```
# Custom .latexmkrc file.

# Always create PDFs and set default engine to LuaLaTeX.
$pdf_mode = 4;
# Set the lualatex variable.
$lualatex = 'lualatex --file-line-error %O %S';

# The next two preview variables are mutually exclusive!
# Preview after each build.
# Equivalent to -pv on command line.
# $preview_mode = 1;
# Preview continuously.
# Equivalent to -pvc on command line.
# $preview_continuous_mode = 1;

# Comment out to use Preview.app.
# Give -pv on the command line.
$pdf_previewer = 'open -a Skim.app %S';

# Special latexmk makeindex line for .dtx files.
$makeindex = "makeindex -s gind.ist %O -o %D %S";

# Files to be cleaned.
$clean_ext = "deriv equ glo gls gsprogs hd listing lol" .
" _minted-%R/* _minted-%R nav snm synctex.gz tcbtemp vpprogs";
```

The very last line is treated as having a comment by the code formatting here, but it is not a comment in the `.latexmkrc` file.