# How to run latexmk with LuaTeX on Windows?

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows, latexmk

This is a bit of a follow-up question to: [Is there latexmk functionality for LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/is-there-latexmk-functionality-for-luatex)

I am trying to setup latexmk on Windows 7 together with LuaTeX but it does not work for some unknown reason. Latexmk in connection with pdftex runs without problems though. With the command line for luatex:

`latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf test.tex`

I get the following output:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 30 March 2012, version: 4.31.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'test.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2012011814 (MiKTeX 2.9)
**
```

Other attempts at changing the latexmk command with the suggested values from the man-page also do not succeed (`latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="lualatex %O %S" test.tex`). Is there any chance of getting this to work?

Comment: Have you tried `latexmk -lualatex test.tex`?

Comment: @Mico: latexmk gives `-lualatex bad option` as an error message then.

Comment: In TeXworks, with TeXlive, I've used the arguments listed in the [TeXworks wiki](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk), just replacing `q/pdflatex` with `q/lualatex`. Works fine for me.

Comment: The command line you quote works perfectly for me (on OS-X with TeXLive 2011).

Comment: Could someone else test if something different happens with a current MikTeX 2.9?  The output from lualatex shown in the question is as if the filename argument disappeared after latexmk's invocation of lualatex.

Comment: Looks like a miktex bug. `lualatex test` works fine but as soon as the `recorder` option is used it stops at the ` ** ` prompt. I will check for updates and if the bug persists I will make a report.

Comment: Until the bug is fixed, a workaround is to invoke `latexmk` with its `-recorder-` option.  Its detection of file dependencies will be suboptimal, but only for difficult cases.

Comment: Thank you all for looking into this! The workaround is working nicely so far and I hope that this bug can be fixed in an upcoming MikTeX release.

Comment: @Ulrike, Alex, ...: Could you please post a short summary answer and accept it then, so that this question is officially concluded. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a MiKTeX bug and I have made a bug report:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3523285&group_id=10783&atid=110783